# How to specify url for submitting search text on Bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am learning to use Search feature of the extended Bootstrap Table.  I declare a table with the following:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover
   table-condensed" id="my_table" border="1"
   data-toggle="table" data-sortable="true"
   data-sort-name="creation_time" data-sort-order="desc"
   data-pagination="true" data-page-size="30"
   data-search="true" data-height="760">

...
</table>
```

The Search text box is shown as expected.  But, I have two problems:

1. How can I specify the destination url for submitting the search text?
2. How to prevent submitting search request when no search text is entered in the search text box?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

you can set the data-url and data-query-params options to solve your problem:

```
<table data-url="your destination url" data-query-params="queryParams" ...></table>

function queryParams(params) {
    if (!params.search) {
        return false; // Return false to stop request.
    }
    return params;
}
```

Here is the docs: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/, and the examples: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html

Comment: I added data-url and data-query-params to my table as advised.  It turns out that the queryParams function is invoked when the table is shown on the web page.  After that, it is not invoked no matter what I entered in the Search box and hit Enter.

Comment: You need to use server side pagination or need to call refresh method when you hit Enter.

Comment: As my application currently does not use server side pagination, I am looking for a lightweight approach to simply prevent search request with a empty string.  I thought it is doable as it looks the table filter is working.  (Unless I am wrong, the table filtering feature is also implemented using server side pagination.)

Comment: Yes, when you use client side, the table search is just filter data from all data you load once. But I think you can refresh method if you need, for example: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/custom-toolbar.html.

Comment: How can I invoke the refresh method when the user simply hits Enter inside the Search box of the table?